# can secrets be deciphered from the proofs generated with ZK-Snarks if a quantum attack were plausible?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, snarks

can secrets be deciphered from the proofs generated with ZK-Snarks if a quantum attack were plausible?

I understand the concern that ZK-snarks and some of their cryptography may be broken by quantum computing in the future.

My question is whether with the proofs generated an attacker could reveal variables of the equations made in the calculations.

some articles mention that if an attacker could break the cryptography of the zk-snarks he could forge proofs and send it to the verifier as valid proof, but could he recover secrets from the proofs?

a related question.

[link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/100041/can-a-circuit-in-a-zk-snark-be-reversed-engineered)

circom circuit as an example:

```
pragma circom 2.1.6;

include "circomlib/poseidon.circom";



template Function() {
    signal input secret;//can the quantum attacker get to secret from the evidence generated in this circuit?
    signal output preimage;

    component hash = Poseidon(1);
    hash.inputs[0] <== secret;

    preimage <== hash.out;

}


component main = Function();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. Basically all SNARK schemes have "perfect zero-knowledge" or "statistical zero-knowledge", meaning they do not rely on any computational assumptions in order to hide the witness. This is true for [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf), [Plonk](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953), [Halo](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/1021), [ZK-STARK](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046), and [Nova](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/370)