# can ownership proofs be added to circuits to make them zk-snark resistant to quantum proof forgery attacks?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, secret-sharing, snarks

According to my previous question the proofs cannot be broken by quantum computation, you cannot obtain the witness of the generated zk-snark proof.

[link to my previous question.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/108388/can-secrets-be-deciphered-from-the-proofs-generated-with-zk-snarks-if-a-quantum)

Now if the concern is that the proofs can be forge, we could add difficulty by using chain integrity proofs:

our circuit should have an output proof-hash for each proof-snark.

```
key=Hash(secret, previous proof-hash).=>ouput
```

and the next proof will be stored in the verifier

```
new-key=Hash(secret, Hash(key) )//in the next interaction key=new-key
new-proof-hash=Hash(new-key). => output
```

the "key" and the "new-proof-hash" is sent  to validate that the circuit has generated the correct hash, then the validator should prove that:

```
if hash(key) == previous proof hash.
    SaveInstorageValidator(new-proof-hash)//in the next interaction it would become previous proof hash
```

and in the next proof zk-snark generated we should follow that same integrity chain, the previous hash is combined with our secret to generate the key, which will be used by the validator. the resistance here is that a proof of our "secret" is generated and combined with a previous hash to generate a key that will be used to validate that we know the secret by revealing the key without revealing our secret.

This would certainly give proof of ownership to the generated proofs because we are using a secret that only the owner should know, and prevent an external party from generating false zk-snark proofs by impersonating our identity based on a "secret".

**Is this circuit feasible for proof of ownership and would it add difficulty for quantum attackers to  forgery proofs?**

Comment: thanks to @rozbb for the previous answer.